# How to create a tensor whose entires are only evaluated at runtime in python?

Tags: python, numpy

let us say I have a tensor A of size 10 by 10 by 10 by 10 by 10, and I define this tensor as A(i1, i2, i3, i4, i5) = 1/(i1 + i2 + i3 + i4 + i5). Obviously, this matrix is of size 10^5, where the number 10 could be larger; hence, I was wondering if there was some way in python to create a numpy matrix where the matrix only forms the entries when it is requested; for example, if we need A(0,0,0,0,0) then it is formed but not A(1,0,0,1,0).

Thanks!

I tried looking through the numpy documentation.

Comment: nothing like that.  A numpy array has all values when created.  You could define a function of 5 integers that returns some value.

Comment: `numpy` is best when using whole-array methods.   `arr+1` or `np.dot(A, B)` are fast compiled operations that work with the whole array.  Selecting individual elements, or iterating through them, e.g. `arr[i, j]` is relatively slow ( say compared to equivalent list access, `alist[i][j[`).   Learn to work with the building blocks that `numpy` provides before trying to push the boundaries.